# How to reliably "clamp" an iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm iterating through a  vector as follows:

```
for(auto it = myVector.begin(); it != myVector.end(); ++it){

    // Do some stuff

}
```

Inside the loop, based on some condition, I add a variable amount to the iterator so as to "jump forward" (but, importantly, never "move back"). What is the "right" way (or, at least, what is an effective/reliable way) to "clamp" the iterator such that I don't end up going beyond the end of the vector (ending up with a program crash or, worse yet, undefined behaviour)?

Comment: Are you talking about `it`? If so, why does the `vector` have to be nested necessarily?

Comment: @cigien Yes, I'm referring to `it`. I'm working in this way as I find that it makes the algorithm contained in the loop more readable. Moreover, there isn't really an incentive for doing this any other way.

Comment: Ok, then why does it have to be `vector<vector<T>>`? Couldn't it just be `vector<T>` and still be the same question?

Comment: @cigien Oh, sorry, yes I see what you're saying now. I'll change the question, as you point out it shouldn't matter. Not sure what I was thinking there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (myVector.end() - it < variable_amount)
    it += variable_amount;
else
    break;
```

Using `std::distance` and `std::advance` would allow this to work with non-random access iterators, but that would be an inefficient algorithm for them, so I recommend not using them.

Algorithm for non-random-access iterators:

```
for (; variable_amount-- && it != myList.end(); ++it);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is how I typically accomplish this, so I guess I've been doing well.

Comment: `distance` and `advance` use + and - for random access iterators, they should be equivalent I think.

Comment: @cigien But they work with non-random access iterators. Using + and - explicitly allows this to break in cases where those would be inefficient so that you don't accidentally end up using them.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm not sure why you're constraining the algorithm to only random access iterators.

Comment: @cigien Simply because this algorithm is efficient only for random access iterators. An efficient algorithm for non-random access iterators is different.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own version of `advance` that will never go past the end iterator. Adapted from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance

```cpp
// Assumes c++11 at least
template<class It, class Distance>
constexpr void clamped_advance(It& it, It limit, Distance n) {
    using category = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category;
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<std::input_iterator_tag, category>::value, "Cannot advance non-input iterator");

    auto dist = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type(n);
    assert(("Can only clamped_advance forward", dist >= 0));

    if (std::is_base_of<std::random_access_iterator_tag, category>::value)
        std::advance(it, std::min(dist, std::distance(it, limit)));
    else
        while (dist-- > 0 && it != limit) ++it;
}
```

And you can use it like:

```cpp
for (auto it = myVector.begin(); it != myVector.end(); ++it) {

    // Do some stuff

    // If this was going to advance past the end, `it` would equal `myVector.end()`
    // and the loop will stop
    clamped_advance(it, myVector.end(), variableAmount);
}
```

Comment: 1. Why not `if constexpr`? 2. If you change the distance's type anyway, why not force the caller to provide the right one? Just make `Distance` non-deduced.

Comment: @Deduplicator 1. For c++11. 2. that's what `std::distance` does. `typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type n` as the parameter would definitely work too

Comment: Ok, yes, point 1 at most speeds compilation insignificantly, though `constexpr` allows you to dispense with `std::advance` and `std::distance`. Regarding point 2, yes I see. Still, forcing to a different type doesn't help any.

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by [getting the distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) between the current iterator and the `begin` iterator.

If that distance plus the offset is larger than the vector size, you're going out of bounds.